# how to convert this solve answer to numeric in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

i solve symbolic equation:

```
>> A=sym('[34618-150*w^2,-16502,0,0,0;-16502,31144-150*w^2,-14642,0,0;0,-14642,27018-150*w^2,-12376,0;0,0,-12376,22447-150*w^2,-10071;0,0,0,-10071,10071-150*w^2]')

A =

[ 34618-150*w^2,        -16502,             0,             0,             0]
[        -16502, 31144-150*w^2,        -14642,             0,             0]
[             0,        -14642, 27018-150*w^2,        -12376,             0]
[             0,             0,        -12376, 22447-150*w^2,        -10071]
[             0,             0,             0,        -10071, 10071-150*w^2]

>> solve(det(A),'w')

ans =

solvelib::Union({[-z1^(1/2), 1], [z1^(1/2), 1]}, z1, RootOf(X19^5 - (20883*X19^4)/25 + (17855633*X19^3)/75 - (11413518430603*X19^2)/421875 + (33558897596166236*X19)/31640625 - 631449249611223316/87890625, X19))
```

how can i convert this symbolic answer to numeric?

i use 'double' but answer isn't correct?

i use vpa but when substitute in determinant can't zero!!!

pleas help me!!

thanks

Comment: to convert symbolic into numeric `inline` is used,for example if `x` is symbolic,you may turn it into numeric by saying: `x=inline(x)`,In your case I think you'll be needing to convert `z1` to inline. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this way:

```
double(solve(det(A),'w'))
```

but I am not quite sure that it's gonna be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

For numerical stuff like this I prefer Mathematica. I put your equation into it and got out the Det as:

```
543676857927080439744 - 80400721107071258400 w^2 + 
 2052468350731440000 w^4 - 18069295320000000 w^6 + 
 63416925000000 w^8 - 75937500000 w^10
```

Not sure if that helps..? Maybe use mupad when doing symbolic calculations.